# Calling a web service in Play framework throwing Execution exception

Tags: java, web-services, rest, playframework

While calling a Web Services using play WS , it is throwing

```
[RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferInputStream@1fecc4f; line: 1, column: 2]]
```

Environment : Ubuntu 12.04 + Java 1.7 + Play Framework 2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is actually `JsonParseException` which means that the `String` which you are actually trying to parse is not a valid JSON. This issue arises because and the response which is received is in XML or HTML and contains the character `<` which is common when the service is not available and the response of the type

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /123 was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

or

```
<data contentType="null" contentLength="0"><![CDATA[]]></data>
```

Try calling the web service through REST client like SOAP UI or PostMan before integrating it with Play framework.